# Convert Order to Quote and Load to Current Cart

Tags: magento-enterprise, orders, sales, quote

I can successfully convert convert an order into quote but I still couldn't load it into current cart. I tried several methods but to no avail. Here's the simplest one:

```
$_quote = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_order')->toQuote($order)->save();
$_quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($_quote->getId());
$_quote->setIsActive(true)->save();
```

I was able to get the quote ID but the quote object doesn't load to the current cart.

I also tried

```
$_quote = Mage::getModel('sales/convert_order')->toQuote($order)->save();
$_quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($_quote->getId());

if ($_checkoutQuote->getId() != $_quote->getId() && $_quote->getId()) {
    $_checkoutQuote->merge($_quote)->save();
    Mage::getModel('checkout/session')
                    ->setQuote($_checkoutQuote)
                    ->init();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setIsActive(true)->save();
}
```

and similar approaches but still not loading the quote. 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@user1240207

Please use the below code. It will may help you.

> Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuoteId($_quote->getId());

Code convert an order to quote  please used below:

```
   $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());
    if ($quote->getId()) {
        $quote->setIsActive(1)
            //->setReservedOrderId(null)
            ->save();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
            ->replaceQuote($quote);
           // ->unsLastRealOrderId();
    }
```

### Here the process:

**Get Current quote**

```
$currenQuoteId=Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId();
```

**Convert Order to quote**

```
$OrderQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());
```

**Active Quote**

```
if ($OrderQuote>getId()) {
    $OrderQuote>setIsActive(1)
        //->setReservedOrderId(null)
        ->save();
}
```

**Merge your current quote and order reverse Quote**

```
if ($OrderQuote->getId() && $currenQuoteId != $OrderQuote->getId()) {
    if ($currenQuoteId) {
    $OrderQuote->merge(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote())
        ->collectTotals()
        ->save();
    }
```

**set quote to  checkout session**

```
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setQuoteId($OrderQuote->getId());

 if (Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->_quote) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->delete();
        }
       Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session') = $OrderQuote;
    } else {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->setCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer())
            ->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)
            ->collectTotals()
            ->save();
    }
```

Comment: Y? what down? please anybody tell us?

Comment: No idea how it was downvoted. But I also checked if it would work, unfortunately it didn't do the trick.

Comment: @KeyulShah,I did not know why some people are down vote without any reason

Comment: @AmitBera : hmm Better Luck Next time.

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer only works if the quote is still available in the DB. I ran into a situation where this was no longer the case, so this code doesn't work:

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());
$quote->getId() => This is empty, in fact the whole model is empty!
```

Instead, we can use the `Mage_Sales_Model_Convert_Order` to convert an existing order back into a new quote using the `toQuote(Mage_Sales_Model_Order $order)` method. It takes an order as input and outputs a new quote object.

You do need to call extra functions for converting the billing/shipping address, items, etc. For each object you will find a function in this class.